# SwiftUI - Share SwiftData View with Widget

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit, swift-data, ios17

I have a SwiftData model called `Diem`. I want my App and my WidgetExtension to share `DiemSharedView` (already having both App and Widget as targets). However, `DiemSharedView` just doesn't show up on my Simulator's widget.

```swift
@Model final class Diem: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var name: String
    var date: Date
    var detail: String?
    
    var id: String { name }

    
    func daysDiff() -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: date).day!
    }
    
    init(name: String, date: Date) {
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
    }
    
    // For Widget intent
    init(entity: DiemEntity) {
        self.name = entity.name
        self.date = entity.date
        self.detail = entity.detail
    }
    
    // Manually conform SwiftData model to Codable from GPT-4 (Bing Chat)
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name, date
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(date, forKey: .date)
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        date = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
    }
}
```

```swift
struct DiemSharedView: View {
    var diem: Diem
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}

struct DiemWidget: Widget {
    // the defaults
}

struct DiemWidgetEntry: TimelineEntry {
    var date: Date
    let diem: Diem?
}

struct DiemWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: DiemWidgetEntry

    var body: some View {
        if let diem: Diem = entry.diem {
            DiemSharedView(diem: diem)  // ISSUE: blank on Simulator
        } else {
            DiemSharedView(diem: .placeholder)  // works (displays when adding the widget on Simulator)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
/*
Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/backyard-birds-sample
See the LICENSE.txt file for this sample’s licensing information.
*/

struct DiemWidgetIntent: WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Select diem"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Keeps track of a diem.")

    @Parameter (title: "Diem")
    var diem: DiemEntity?
    
    init(diem: DiemEntity) {
        self.diem = diem
    }

    init() {}
    
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary {
            \.$diem
        }
    }
}

extension DiemWidgetIntent {
    static var christmas: DiemWidgetIntent {
        let intent = DiemWidgetIntent()
        intent.diem = .init(from: .christmas)
        return intent
    }
    
    static var independenceDay: DiemWidgetIntent {
        let intent = DiemWidgetIntent()
        intent.diem = .init(from: .independenceDay)
        return intent
    }
}

struct DiemEntity: AppEntity, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var date: Date
    var detail: String?
    
    var id: String {
        name
    }
    
    func daysDiff() -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: date).day!
    }

    init(name: String, date: Date) {
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
    }

    init(from diem: Diem) {
        name = diem.name
        date = diem.date
    }

    var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
        DisplayRepresentation(title: "\(name)")
    }

    static var typeDisplayRepresentation = TypeDisplayRepresentation(name: "Diem")
    static var defaultQuery = DiemEntityQuery()
}

struct DiemEntityQuery: EntityQuery, Sendable {
    func entities(for identifiers: [DiemEntity.ID]) async throws -> [DiemEntity] {
        let modelContext = ModelContext(try! ModelContainer(for: Schema([Diem.self])))
        let diems = try modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Diem>(predicate: #Predicate { identifiers.contains($0.id) }))
        return diems.map { DiemEntity(from: $0) }
    }
    
    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [DiemEntity] {
        let modelContext = ModelContext(try! ModelContainer(for: Schema([Diem.self])))
        let diems = try modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Diem>())
        return diems.map { DiemEntity(from: $0) }
    }
}
```

```swift
/*
Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/backyard-birds-sample
See the LICENSE.txt file for this sample’s licensing information.
*/
struct DiemWidgetProvider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> DiemWidgetEntry {
        DiemWidgetEntry(date: Date(), configuration: DiemWidgetIntent())
    }

    func snapshot(for configuration: DiemWidgetIntent, in context: Context) async -> DiemWidgetEntry {
        DiemWidgetEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration)
    }
    
    func timeline(for configuration: DiemWidgetIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<DiemWidgetEntry> {
        var entries: [DiemWidgetEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = DiemWidgetEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration)
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        return Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    }
}
```

All the previews work. `DiemEntityQuery` works.

Comment: This could possibly happen if your widget extension crashes or takes long time to fetch data. If you select run target to your widget module and run, you can see your widget's log in Xcode console. Can you attach what does log say?

Comment: Widgets/DiemWidgetProvider.swift:51 (`let diem = try! modelContext.fetch...`: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
But I don't think that's the problem?

Comment: Also when I select run target to my Widget Extension the icon is a blue circle with an E in the middle, probably because I had renamed my Widget Extension from "PropediumWidgetExtension" to "Widget". Does that affect anything? btw does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: The crash is the problem. That prevents you from render the widget. I think your second question will not affect something.

Comment: OK I fixed the first crash by making the placeholder value static. Now I have 
`Thread 7: Fatal error: Couldn't find \Diem.id on Diem with fields [SwiftData.Schema.PropertyMetadata(name: "name", keypath: \Diem.name, defaultValue: nil, metadata: Optional(Attribute - name: , options: [unique], valueType: Any, defaultValue: nil, hashModifier: nil)), SwiftData.Schema.PropertyMetadata(name: "date", keypath: \Diem.date, defaultValue: nil, metadata: nil), SwiftData.Schema.PropertyMetadata(name: "detail", keypath: \Diem.detail, defaultValue: nil, metadata: nil)]`
when fetching in DiemEntity.entities